# Can't seem to get Tensorflow's tf.metrics.auc working

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, metrics, auc

Tensorflow has a function to calculate AUC: tf.metrics.auc(). Here is my a section of my code trying to compute auc:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {x : x_train, y : y_train, p_keep_input: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})
        avg_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x : x_train, y : y_train, p_keep_input: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})

        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            training_acc = accuracy.eval({x : x_train, y : y_train, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
            print("Epoch:", '%03d' % (epoch), "Training Accuracy:", '%.5f' % (training_acc), "cost=", "{:.5f}".format(avg_cost))

    print("Optimization Done!")


    roc_score = tf.metrics.auc(y, pred)
    roc_score = tf.convert_to_tensor(roc_score)
    print(roc_score.eval({x : x_test, y : y_test, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0}))
```

Any section of the error I get is below. The entire error is quite lengthy.

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value auc_4/false_positives
     [[Node: auc_4/false_positives/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@auc_4/false_positives"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](auc_4/false_positives)]]
```

I'd appreciate any pointers on how to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: The change below allowed to code to run without errors: `roc_score = tf.metrics.auc(y, pred)
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(roc_score, feed_dict={x : x_test, y : y_test, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0}))`. The challenge now is that I get an AUC score of 0.0. I can't figure what is wrong at this point.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422508/tensorflow-attempting-to-use-uninitialized-value-auc-auc-auc-false-positives

Answer (score 2):

might be too late now but if you haven't found the solution, try this change:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
_,roc_score = tf.metrics.auc(y, pred)
print(sess.run(roc_score, feed_dict={x : x_test, y : y_test, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0}))
```