# Tensorflow Attempting to use uninitialized value AUC/AUC/auc/false_positives

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a CNN using for image classification. Due to the limited size of my data set I'm using transfer learning. Basically, I'm using the pre-trained network Google is proving in its retrain example (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining).

The model works great and gives a very good accuracy. But my dataset is highly imbalance which mean accuracy is not the best metric to judge the performance of the model.

By looking into different solutions, some suggested changing the sampling method or the performance metric used. I'm choosing to go with the later.

Tensorflow provides a good verity of metrics including, AUC, precision, recall, etc.

Now, here is the code of the retraing model: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

I'm adding the following to `add_evaluation_step(result_tensor, ground_truth_tensor)` function:

```
  with tf.name_scope('AUC'):
    with tf.name_scope('prediction'):
        prediction = tf.argmax(result_tensor, 1)
    with tf.name_scope('AUC'):
        auc_value = tf.metrics.auc(tf.argmax(ground_truth_tensor, 1), prediction, curve='ROC')


  tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', evaluation_step)
  tf.summary.scalar('AUC', auc_value)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py",
>   line 1135, in 
>       tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 44, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py",
>   line 911, in main
>       ground_truth_input: train_ground_truth})   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 767, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 965, in _run
>       feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1015, in _do_run
>       target_list, options, run_metadata)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1035, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:
>   Attempting to use uninitialized value AUC/AUC/auc/false_positives
>   [[Node: AUC/AUC/auc/false_positives/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@AUC/AUC/auc/false_positives"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
>
> Caused by op u'AUC/AUC/auc/false_positives/read', defined at:   File
>   "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py",
>   line 1135, in 
>       tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 44, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py",
>   line 874, in main
>       final_tensor, ground_truth_input)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py",
>   line 806, in add_evaluation_step
>       auc_value, update_op = tf.metrics.auc(tf.argmax(ground_truth_tensor, 1), prediction,
>   curve='ROC')   File
>   "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py",
>   line 555, in auc
>       labels, predictions, thresholds, weights)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py",
>   line 473, in _confusion_matrix_at_thresholds
>       false_p = _create_local('false_positives', shape=[num_thresholds])   File
>   "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py",
>   line 177, in _create_local
>       validate_shape=validate_shape)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 226, in **init**
>       expected_shape=expected_shape)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 344, in _init_from_args
>       self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")   File
>   "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 1490, in identity
>       result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)   File
>   "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 768, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2402, in create_op
>       original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)   File "/home/user_2/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1264, in **init**
>       self._traceback = _extract_stack()
>
> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use
>   uninitialized value AUC/AUC/auc/false_positives    [[Node:
>   AUC/AUC/auc/false_positives/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@AUC/AUC/auc/false_positives"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

But I don't understand why is this because in the main I have this:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this:

```
init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But why? What does tf.local_variables_initializer() do?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman besides trainiable variables you create with `tf.Variable` or `tf.get_variable`, there are untrainable variables like global step which increase one after each train step, these variables all called local variables, if you want to calculate AUC, tensorflow implicitly create some local variables for it, so you also need to initialize it

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks :)